# Multiple Node Process Detection Specificity

Tags: node.js, process, operating-system

I was wondering if it possible to detect which node process (in this case the server is running more than one) a specific processid represents. When I parse the list of processes running, the paths of all the node applications come from the same path (ie "X:\PathToNode\node.exe"). I've found that I can get the command line name of the script such as "app.js" which is useful so long as you always name the main script some thing different for each app running on the server. Below is an example using process-list npm package.

```
snapshot('name', 'pid', 'path', 'cmdline').then(tasks => {
tasks.forEach(task => {
    if(task.name.indexOf('node') > -1){
        processList.push(task);
    }
});
console.log(processList);
```

Is there any way to differentiate between different node processes that would not require me to use different file names for the main node process in each project?

Comment: You would need a way of differentiating it. For example, you can get all the processes using `app.js` and the one with the lowest pid can be assumed to be the first instance, the next will be the next instance, and so on.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer There is no order in which the node processes are started (independent of each other). So lowest pid/first instance isn't relevant in this case because each node process is a different script.

Comment: Oh I see. It looks like you can change `process.title` that will be reflected in the `ps ax` output.

Comment: so if each `app.js` has it's own `process.title = "giraffe";` and another `app.js` has a `process.title = "monkey";` you can differentiate between the apps when calling `ps ax | grep -iE 'monkey|giraffe'`